# How do I change a segue based on a UISwitch?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uistoryboard, xcode11

I'm trying to make a settings tab that changes what view the user sees in a different tab based on a UISwitch. How would I make it so that when the switch is on then the user changes to that tab, it goes to `ViewController1` and when the switch is off and they change tabs, it goes to `ViewController2`? I've attached a screenshot that might explain it a bit better. I censored the information that would give away my app's purpose so as to not attract copycats and whatnot.

[image: ViewControllers in and the segue between them]

As you can see, my main problem with presenting modally full screen is that the TabBarController is eliminated, leaving users with no way of turning off the setting or looking at another tab. I don't want to present it as a popover tab or push it, because I want it to feel like nothing ever happened.

The larger view will appear modally when the switch is on and `viewWillAppear` is called on `ViewController1`. Here's my code for that:

SettingsView.swift

```
import UIKit

class SettingsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var viewSwitch: UISwitch!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        tableView.allowsSelection = false
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    @IBAction func switchIsChanged(_ sender: Any) {
        if viewSwitch.isOn == true{
            TableViewController.switchState = true
        }
        if viewSwitch.isOn == false{
            TableViewController.switchState = false
        }
    }
}
```

I've moved the code from TabBar.swift to TableView.swift because the solution I tried doesn't really regard the `TabBarController`. Here's TableView.swift:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    public static var switchState: Bool?

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if TableViewController.switchState == true {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "LargeViewSegue", sender: self)
        }
        else {
            print("Showing standard view.")
        }
    }
}
```

This code works, but as I said before, it shows no `TabBar`, which is essential to my app. The ideal solution is to change the relationship segue from the `TabBarController` to the `LargeView`/`TableView`. Unfortunately, from what I've heard, You can't create custom relationship segues programatically. If someone could prove me wrong, that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either I'm misreading something, or you haven't *fully* described the problem enough for me to duplicate the issue you're facing. A `UISwitch` has a `Bool` property called `isOn`. To direct navigation seems pretty simple to do based on that flag/property. Is there some code you could post? (I'm one of those "old school" coders who prefer to not use storyboards, so maybe your issue is more about which segue to use. If so, I think that while YES, you CANNOT create and use a `UISegue` in code, I think that YES, you CAN execute a specific "storyboard-defined" segue through code.)

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to *execute* the segue, I simply want to create a relationship segue that can be used when switching the tab later on (I'll edit the question with some code for you).